# Collect tracking code - session info/time on page

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

We're implementing the Collect tracking code and managed to retrieve the page views in the MC PI Data Extensions. Are we also able to retrieve the session time & length? Or even better, the time on page per page view?

If so, any tips on how to achieve this are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no - this information is not being collected by the Web & Mobile Analytics collect code, and it is not possible to extend the scope of what is being collected. It is focused on storing information on which categories and catalogue items your visitors have been viewing, and that's it.